# AngularJS and ¤compiler

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have started to study angularJs directives. I have an example that I can't understand

The full source code is in the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EhAgXT?p=info)

```
var detailTemplate = $compile(element.find("div.detail")
    .replaceWith(replacementMarkup));;  
return a function.
```

Here the scope is global, I mean, is the scope of controller and I can see 
the collection images (the recipies), I think.....

what I can't understand is how the old div is retrieved

```
<div class="detail">
    <img ng-src="{{recipy.img}}" />
</div>
```

and how the right image is shown; ng-repeat is called again?

and when I do this:

```
detailTemplate(scope, function(detail) {
    target.replaceWith(detail);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, this code is unnecessarily complex, this can be done much more easily. ng-repeat is called just once. With that ng-repeat, you are generating the tiles that runs the event "$(element).parent().on("mouseenter" ... ". When that event is fired, it's retrieving the element and running that compile function. That compile is replacing the "replacementMarkup", wich is probably just some html with the image, and compiling it (you must compile any code you insert into angular).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, yes this example is complicated, but here, the goal is to show the power of $compile. we have replaced the DOM div.detail at compile time by <!-- defer-show-detail --\> and when the event is fired, it's looking for node type DIV where has "defer-show-detail" for content and we can check that target.length is greater than zero,  so true. How detailTemplate can do the association beetwen old node and the new node? thanks.